# Let $A = P(P({1}))$. Find $A$ and $|A|$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know that $P(1) = \left \{ \varnothing, \left \{1\right \} \right \}$ and $|P(1)| = 2^1 = 2.$

$P(\left \{ \varnothing, \left \{1\right \} \right \}) = \left \{ \varnothing, \left \{1\right \}, \left \{ \varnothing, \left \{1\right \} \right \} \right \}$ but this has cardinality $3 \neq 2^2 = 4$.

So is $P(\left \{ \varnothing, \left \{1\right \} \right \}) = \left \{ \varnothing, \varnothing, \left \{1\right \}, \left \{ \varnothing, {1} \right \} \right \}$? But this makes no sense to me.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you mean $\varnothing$ when you write $\Phi$, but do you also mean $\{\varnothing\}$ when you write $1$?

Comment: What you have written looks to me more like the _successor_ than the power set.

Comment: Fixed it, when I do {1} in $ signs, it only shows 1. Had to use \left \{  \right \} instead.

Comment: You don't need the `\left` and `\right` modifiers if you're not using large fonts, displayed fractions (or other similar symbols), or superscript and subscript letters. Using `\{` and `\}` is enough. This should also not surprise you if you know a bit of $\rm\LaTeX$ either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm supposing that you mean $\varnothing$ when you write $\Phi$.

The correct set is:

$$P(\left \{ \varnothing, {1} \right \}) = \left \{ \varnothing, \{1\},\{\varnothing\}, \left \{ \varnothing, {1} \right \} \right \}$$

and then

$$|P(\left \{ \varnothing, {1} \right \})|=2^2=4$$

Once $\varnothing$ is a element of the set $\{\varnothing,1\}$ then $\{\varnothing\}$ is a subset that you are missing. For the same reason you also have to write $\{1\}$ instead of $1$.